# How dropwizard handles concurrency?

Tags: concurrency, dropwizard

I have to create a presentaion on dropwizard and some of the main points my professor wants me to focus are concurrency handling, performance of dropwizard.

I googled dropwizard, dropwizard concurrency, how dropwizard handles concurrency, but didn't got any appropriate answer.

So please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the thing with dropwizard is, that all it does is pull together standards and plug them together for you in a way that requires very little effort on your side. So DW itself does not provide concurrency and performance for you, it provides you with the components that do.

With regards to your question, you need to ask it differently in order to answer it for DW. Technically your answer is: DW does not provide concurrency.

You also need to limit (or not) your search a bit. DW provides many extensions, I am going to focus on core: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html

Core provides you with Jetty, Jersey, Jackson etc. Now you can google the components, because these are the concurrency providers. For example:

Jetty: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/High_Load
Jersey: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html

and so on ..

So jetty provides an embedded webserver that allows you to have hundreds and thousands of requests. 
Jersey with a client like Apache NIO (async client) provides you with a framework doing hundreds and requests against a different REST API.

So you see, in order to work out how DW handles concurrency (and I am assuming you mean in terms of request handling), you will have to read up on what jetty provides for this. Same with Jersey in case you mean making asynchronous requests.

I hope that helps,

Artur